# Call extension's phtml file in CMS page editor

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, cms

I am using extension for Daily deals. It's displaying active deals in the sidebar.

But i have to display this in the Home page so i am adding following code in the editor of Home page.

```
{{block class="dailydeal/sidebar_activedeal" template="mw_dailydeal/sidebar/activedeal.phtml"}}
```

but nothing is displaying on the front side.

When i am using another test file it's displaying output.

```
{{block class="core/template" template=mw_dailydeal/sidebar/test.phtml"}}
```

in layout file it's as following:

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="dailydeal/sidebar_todaydeal" name="todaydeal_left" before="-">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template helper="dailydeal/sidebar/displayTodaydealLeft"/>
            </action>
        </block>
        <block type="dailydeal/sidebar_activedeal" name="activedeal_left" after="todaydeal_left">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template helper="dailydeal/sidebar/displayActivedealLeft"/>
            </action>
        </block>
        <block type="dailydeal/sidebar_calendar" name="calendar_left" after="activedeal_left">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template helper="dailydeal/sidebar/displayCalendarLeft"/>
            </action>
        </block>
</reference>
```

In block file as following :

```
class MW_Dailydeal_Block_Sidebar_Activedeal extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
}
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your block `dailydeal/sidebar_activedeal` to whitelist.

In admin go to **System->Permissions->Blocks**. Here add your block with status **allowed**.

Comment: Yes i have added but still not working.

Comment: you are missing starting quote (") in `template=mw_dailydeal/sidebar/activedeal.phtml"`

Comment: No it's ok in magento i have just missed in question.

Comment: i have to change anything else in {{block class="dailydeal/sidebar_activedeal" template="mw_dailydeal/sidebar/activedeal.phtml"}}

Comment: try changing class to type